# Dealing with Islands with sf objects and the tmap package

Tags: r, sp, sf, ggplot2, ggmap

I have the bounderies for the municipalities in the "capital region" of Denmark. The acctual map looks like this:

[image]

The yellow island is the fourth row in my sf object.

[image]

I am trying to folllow the example at the end of section 8.2.7 in this book ([link](https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/adv-map.html#inset-maps)). That is I need to make the yellow island smaller and move it closer to the rest. Also there seems not to be any tags for tmap, but that is the package the link uses.

I have tried this code:

```
RH <- geo %>%
  filter(REGIONKODE=="1084") %>% 
  select(KOMNAVN, AREAL)  %>% 
  filter(!(KOMNAVN  %in% c("Christiansø", "Bornholm"))) %>% 
  arrange(KOMNAVN)


Bornholm <- geo %>% 
  filter(KOMNAVN=="Bornholm")

mainland <-  tm_shape(RH, projection = 2163) + tm_polygons() + 
  tm_layout(frame = FALSE)  

Bornholm_map   <-  tm_shape(Bornholm) + tm_polygons() + 
  tm_layout(title = "Bornholm", frame = FALSE, bg.color = NA, 
            title.position = c("LEFT", "BOTTOM"))
mainland 
print(Bornholm_map, vp = viewport(x = 0.35, y = 0.1, width = 0.2, height = 0.1))
```

This just rotates the plot with 90 dergrees and the island gets lost and I get this  error message

```
Error in viewport(x = 0.35, y = 0.1, width = 0.2, height = 0.1) : 
  could not find function "viewport"
```

[image]

Comment: How far have you got in trying? Is it not working? Does it look wrong? Error messages?

Comment: @ Spacedman: I do not know what projection to use. I have added some code to my question.

Comment: @ Spacedman: The question has been updated. I think the problem is the error ``could not find function "viewport``. Also I am not able to install the package ``spDataLarge`` with my version of ``r``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search for the word "viewport" in that text you'll see this:

> Finally, we combine the two maps. A viewport from the grid package can
>   be used by stating a center location (x and y) and a size (width and
>   height) of the inset map.
>
> ```
> library(grid)
> ```

So do `library(grid)` to bring in the `viewport` function.

Comment: @ Thanks Spaceman. I am going to update the question. I have a new problem which is that the legend colors don't seem to be correct for the island.

Comment: Okay but that's a new question, not really an update. This question should really be called "Could not find "viewport" function". Keep things minimal.

Comment: @ Spaceman: I got your message too late. Can we keep this post. The title is still relevant.

Comment: @ Spacedman: I have changed it back.